# select multiple columns in a single column with space in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have three columns called first name, last name, middle name I want to combine all these and add in another table with column name full name

ex- first name = Ram
last name = Kumar

select first name ||middle name || last name,* from users I am getting Ramkumar
how can I add space between these columns so that I can get output Ram  Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Just add the space into the concatenation:

```
SELECT 
    first_name || ' ' || middle_name || ' ' || last_name,
    * 
FROM users
```